# FFMPEG is not working in AWS lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am trying to convert a video file into an audio file using AWS lambda function whenever a file is uploaded into an S3 bucket. So I am using FFMPEG for converting a video file into audio. But I keep getting this error while converting a video file. I have seen similar questions but none of the solutions is not working for me. So If anyone knows please share your solutions.

**Error message**

```
    TypeError: Cannot create property 'stack' on string 
'Could not find ffmpeg executable, tried "/var/task/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg" and "/var/task/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg"'
```

**Code**

```
    const
    ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path,
    ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

    // set ffmpeg package path
    ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
    function convert(input, output, callback) {
        ffmpeg(input)
            .output(output)
            .on('end', function() {                    
                console.log('conversion ended');
                callback(null);
            }).on('error', function(err){
                console.log('error: ', err.code, err.msg);
                callback(err);
            }).run();
    }

    exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
        const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        console.log("key ", key);
        console.log("event ", event.Records[0].s3);
        convert(key, `/tmp/${key}.mp3`, function(err){
            if(!err) {
                console.log('conversion complete');
            } else {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    }


    const
        ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path,
        ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

    // set ffmpeg package path
    ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
    function convert(input, output, callback) {
        ffmpeg(input)
            .output(output)
            .on('end', function() {                    
                console.log('conversion ended');
                callback(null);
            }).on('error', function(err){
                console.log('error: ', err.code, err.msg);
                callback(err);
            }).run();
    }

    exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
        const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        console.log("key ", key);
        console.log("event ", event.Records[0].s3);
        convert(key, `/tmp/${key}.mp3`, function(err){
            if(!err) {
                console.log('conversion complete');
            } else {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

**package.json**

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.0.17",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  }
```

Comment: Did you include ffmpeg executable and the dependencies in you Lambda bundle? https://intoli.com/blog/transcoding-on-aws-lambda/

Comment: Do you mean node_modules?

Comment: No. Usually these libraries just delegate the call to actual ffmpeg executable (a C++ executable). See link for a python example. In general try to do this on an ec2 instance to understand how it works and how all pieces for together.

Comment: Hi @kashyap this code is working fine in my local but not working in a lambda function. I am totally confused please help to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg needs to be installed, the npm package does not install ffmpeg, only the bindings. but you can use lambda layers, fortunately under https://github.com/mthenw/awesome-layers a ffmpeg layer is listed which you can include in your project

Comment: Yeah, I tried but that code gives me an error message and I posted that error as a separate question. This is the link to that question ( [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429560/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-aws-lambda-function?noredirect=1#comment95671277_54429560] ).

Comment: but the original question is answered, isn't it? please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the package (in this case the ffmpeg) is successfully installed when you are running your Lambda function.

Normally the '**Cannot find XXX**' on Lambda is a good indicator to tell the package is not installed, even with your package.json having the ffmpeg listed under the 'dependencies' section.

As a common practice: ***Lambda will try to install all the dependencies in the package.json and will throw errors if the dependencies cannot be installed***, and ***that is the time you should consider using the Lambda Layer as an add-on***.

Just as you can tell, the Lambda layer is a good component to add extra dependencies when normal npm install does not work. The lambda layer could fix the problem of 'Cannot find XXX'.

Please refer https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer.

And also in the [official documentation of AWS Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html), it's telling us how to get extra contents installed as a .zip dependency.